# Minesweeper issue with recursion function in C

Tags: c, recursion, minesweeper

I'm trying to create a terminal version of the game minesweeper in C for a programing class. I'm only part way through the project and I've encountered a problem I can't seem to solve. I'm trying to create a function that, when a location, uncovers the square and then recursively calls itself to uncover any neighboring squares that do not contain mines. The function seems to work except that it will sometimes leave a square hidden which is not surrounded by any mines.

Here's an example of the issue, it seems like its only an issue when the number of mines is really low in this case 4:

[image]

Here is my source code forgive me if it's not the best I'm just learning C.

```
//
//  main.c
//  Minesweeper
//
//  

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "game.h"
#include "io.h"

int X=20;
int Y=20;
int M=4;

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    int **intboard = allocateBoard(X,Y,M); // initalizes board X by Y and randomly places M mines.

    numberBoard(intboard, X, Y); // assigns numbers of mines around each square.

    char **charboard = allocateVisableBoard(X,Y); // allocates a board which keeps track of what is visable and what is not. '-' = not visible ' ' = visable

    display(intboard, charboard, X, Y); // function which displays values that are visable

    system("clear");

    int **checkboard = initCheckboard(X,Y); // board which is used by reveal function so it knows which squares have already been checked

    int status = reveal(intboard, charboard,checkboard, X, Y, 5, 5,0); // reveals the value at 5,5 and recursively reveals squares as necessary

    display(intboard, charboard, X, Y);

    if (status == 1) //displays loosing screen if mine is chosen
        boom();

    if ( 1 == endofgame(intboard, charboard, X, Y))
        printf("you win!");

    return 0;
}

//
//game.c
//Minesweeper
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "game.h"

#define MVALUE -1 //minevalue
#define KNRM  "\x1B[0m"
#define KRED  "\x1B[31m"
#define KGRN  "\x1B[32m"
#define KYEL  "\x1B[33m"
#define KBLU  "\x1B[34m"
#define KMAG  "\x1B[35m"
#define KCYN  "\x1B[36m"
#define KWHT  "\x1B[37m"
#define BOARD  "\x1B[37;44m"
#define RESET   "\033[0m"

int **allocateBoard(int X, int Y, int M) /* Allocates board X by Y with M mines  */
{
    /* Check if allocation succeeded. (check for NULL pointer) */
    int i,j,x,y,**board;

    board = malloc(X*sizeof(int *));
    for(i = 0 ; i < X ; i++)
        board[i] = malloc(Y*sizeof(int));

    /*int modulo = (X*Y)/(double) M;    

    printf("modulo: %d\n", modulo);
    */

   for(i = 0 ; i < X ; i++)
        for(j = 0 ; j < Y ; j++)
            board[i][j] = 0;

    int r = (rand() % (X*Y));
    for(i = 0; i < M;)
    {
        y = r/Y;
        x = r %X;
        if(board[x][y] == 0)
        {
            board[x][y] = MVALUE;
            i++;
        }

        r =rand() % (X*Y);
    }
    return board;
}

int adjacentMines(int **board,int X, int Y, int x, int y)
{
    int count = 0;
    if(x < X-1)
        if(board[y][x+1]== MVALUE)
            count++;
    if(x > 0)
        if(board[y][x-1] == MVALUE)
            count++;
    if(y < Y-1)
        if(board[y+1][x]== MVALUE)
            count++;
    if(y > 0)
        if(board[y-1][x]== MVALUE)
            count++;
    if(x < X-1 && y < Y-1)
        if(board[y+1][x+1]== MVALUE)
            count++;
    if(x > 0 && y < Y-1)
        if(board[y+1][x-1]== MVALUE)
            count++;
    if(x < X-1 && y > 0)
        if(board[y-1][x+1]== MVALUE)
            count++;
    if(x > 0 && y > 0)
        if(board[y-1][x-1]== MVALUE)
            count++;

    // TESTING CODE
    /*
    printf("x:%d y:%d mines adjacent:%d\n",x,y,count);    
    */
    return count;
}

void printIntBoard(int **board,int X,int Y)
{
    int i,j;
    system("clear");
    printf("       ");
    for(i=0; i < X; i++)
        printf("[%.3d] ",i);
    printf("\n\n ");

    for(i=0;i < Y; i++)
    {
        printf("[%.3d] ",i);

        for(j=0; j < X; j++)
        {
            if(board[i][j] == -1)
            {
                printf("  *  ");
            }
            else
                printf("  %d  ",board[i][j]);
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n\n ");

    }
}

void printCharBoard(char **board,int X,int Y)
{
    int i,j;

    printf("       ");

    for(i = 0; i < X; i++)
        printf("[%.3d] ",i);

    printf("\n\n ");

    for(i=0;i < Y; i++)
    {
        printf("[%.3d] ",i);

        for(j = 0; j < X; j++)
        {
            printf("  %c  ",board[i][j]);
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n\n ");

    }
}

void numberBoard(int **board,int X, int Y)
{
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < X; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < Y ; j++)
        {
            if(board[j][i]!= -1)
                board[j][i]=adjacentMines(board, X, Y, i, j);
        }
    }
}

char **allocateVisableBoard(int X, int Y) /* Allocates Visable board X by Y completely hidden */
{
    int i,j;
    char **board;

    board = malloc(X*sizeof(char *));
    for(i = 0 ; i < X ; i++)
        board[i] = malloc(Y*sizeof(char));

    for(i = 0 ; i < X ; i++)
        for(j = 0 ; j < Y ; j++)
            board[i][j] = '-';

    return board;
}

void showBoard(int **iboard, char **cboard,int X, int Y)
{
    int i,j;

    for(i = 0; i < X; i++)
        {
            for (j=0; j<Y; j++) {
                printf("  %c  ",cboard[j][i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
}

int **initCheckboard(int X,int Y)
{
    int i,j, **checkboard;

    checkboard = malloc(X *sizeof(int *));
    for (i = 0; i < X; i++) {
        checkboard[i]= malloc(Y *sizeof(int));
    }

    for(i = 0 ; i < X ; i++)
        for(j = 0 ; j < Y ; j++)
            checkboard[i][j] = 0;

    return checkboard;
}


int reveal(int **iboard,char **cboard,int **checkboard, int X, int Y, int x, int y,int count)
{
    if(count == 0 && iboard[x][y]== MVALUE)
    {
        cboard[x][y] = ' ';
        checkboard[x][y] = 1;
        return 1;
    }


    if (iboard[y][x] > 0)
    {
        cboard[y][x] = ' ';
        checkboard[y][x] = 1;
        return 0;
    }

    else if(iboard[y][x] == 0)
    {
        checkboard[y][x] = 1;
        count ++;

        if(x < X-1 && checkboard[y][x+1] == 0)
        {
            cboard[y][x]= ' ';
            checkboard[y][x+1] = 1;
            reveal(iboard, cboard, checkboard, X, Y, x+1, y,count);
        }
        if(y < Y-1 && checkboard[y+1][x] == 0)
        {
            cboard[y][x]= ' ';
            checkboard[y+1][x] = 1;
            reveal(iboard, cboard, checkboard, X, Y, x, y+1,count);
        }
        if(x > 0 && checkboard[y][x-1] == 0)
        {
            cboard[y][x]= ' ';
            checkboard[y][x-1] = 1;
            reveal(iboard, cboard, checkboard, X, Y, x-1, y,count);
        }
        if(y > 0 && checkboard[y-1][x] == 0)
        {
            cboard[y][x]= ' ';
            checkboard[y-1][x] = 1;
            reveal(iboard, cboard, checkboard, X, Y, x, y-1,count);
        }
        if(x < X-1 && y < Y-1 && checkboard[y+1][x+1] == 0)
        {
            cboard[y][x]= ' ';
            checkboard[y+1][x+1] = 1;
            reveal(iboard, cboard, checkboard, X, Y, x+1, y+1,count);
        }
        if(x < X-1 && y > 0 && checkboard[y-1][x+1] == 0)
        {
            cboard[y][x]= ' ';
            checkboard[y-1][x+1] = 1;
            reveal(iboard, cboard, checkboard, X, Y, x+1, y-1,count);
        }
        if(x > 0 && y > 0 && checkboard[y-1][x-1] == 0)
        {
            cboard[y][x]= ' ';
            checkboard[y-1][x-1] = 1;
            reveal(iboard, cboard, checkboard, X, Y, x-1, y-1,count);
        }
        if(x > 0 && y < Y-1 && checkboard[y+1][x-1] == 0)
        {
            cboard[y][x]= ' ';
            checkboard[y+1][x-1] = 1;
            reveal(iboard, cboard, checkboard, X, Y, x-1, y+1,count);
        }

    }
        return 0;
}

int endofgame(int **iboard,char **cboard,int X,int Y)
{
    int i,j;
    int count = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < Y; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < X; j++)
        {
            if(cboard[i][j] == '-')
            {
                if (iboard[i][j] != MVALUE)
                    count++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (count == 0)
        return 1; // win

    else
        return 0; // keep going
}

void resetcheck(int **checkboard,int X, int Y)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0 ; i < X ; i++)
        for(j = 0 ; j < Y ; j++)
            checkboard[i][j] = 0;


}

//
//  io.c
//  Minesweeper
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "game.h"
#include "scanner.h"

void boom(void)
{
    system("clear");
    printf("Boom!");                                                                                                                                                                                                        

}

void display(int **iboard, char **cboard,int X,int Y)
{
    int i,j;

    printf("      ");
    for (i =0 ;i < X; i++)
        printf("[%.3d]",i);

    printf("\n\n");

    for (i = 0; i < Y; i++) {
        printf("[%.3d]",i);
        for (j = 0; j < X; j++) {
            if (cboard[i][j]==' ') {
                if (iboard[i][j] == -1)
                    printf("  *  ");

                //else if(iboard[i][j] == 0)
                //printf("      ");

                else
                    printf("  %d  ",iboard[i][j]);
            }
            else
                printf("  %c  ",cboard[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }

}

//
//  mine.h
//  Minesweeper
//

extern int **allocateBoard(int X, int Y, int M);
extern int adjacentMines(int **board,int X, int Y, int x, int y);
extern void printIntBoard(int **board,int X,int Y);
extern void numberBoard(int **board,int X, int Y);
extern char **allocateVisableBoard(int X, int Y);
extern void printCharBoard(char **board,int X,int Y);
extern int **initCheckboard(int X,int Y);
extern int reveal(int **iboard,char **cboard,int **checkboard, int X, int Y, int x, int y,int count);
extern int endofgame(int **iboard,char **cboard,int X,int Y);
extern void resetcheck(int **checkboard,int X, int Y);
extern void showBoard(int **iboard, char **cboard,int X, int Y);

//
//  io.h
//  Minesweeper
//

extern void display(int **iboard, char **cboard,int X,int Y);
extern void boom(void);
```

The problem should be with my reveal function which is lines 251 to 324.

Comment: Why not post the code?

Comment: could you explain what each parameter represents?

Comment: Learn to use the debugger and narrow it down a bit

Comment: @Ed Heal unfortunately I haven't learned how to use a debugger in my class. But if you know any good tutorials on how to use one I'd try.

Comment: @user3404144 - Depends on the compiler. It is just like getting a mew things. Need to read the manual. Give it a god and learn on the way.

Answer (score 1):

In your reveal function (and others) you are switching between using [x][y] and [y][x] against the same array.

Comment: You're right I'm going to have to fix that. Would that be the problem?

Comment: @user3404144 well was it?